# Passing arguments to Spring tests

Tags: spring, junit4, spring-test

We have a standard Spring test class which loads an application context:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:app-context.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class AppTest {
   ...
}
```

The XML context uses standard placeholders e.g.: `${key}` When the full application is run normally (not as a test), the main class will load the application context as follows so that the command line arguments are seen by Spring :

```
PropertySource ps = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(args);
context.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(ps);
context.load("classpath:META-INF/app-context.xml");
context.refresh();
context.start();
```

When running the Spring test, what code needs to be added to ensure that program arguments (e.g. `--key=value`): are passed from the IDE (in our case Eclipse) into the application context?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, not because of Spring, see this other question on SO with an explanation:

- [Passing JUnit command line parameters in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683764/passing-junit-command-line-parameters-in-eclipse)

If you decide to use JVM arguments (`-Dkey=value` format) in Eclipse instead, it's easy in Spring to use those values:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:app-context.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class AppTest {
   
    @Value("#{systemProperties[key]}")
    private String argument1;

    ...

}
```

Or, without `@Value` and just using a property placeholder:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:META-INF/spring/test-app-context.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ExampleConfigurationTests {
    
    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @Test
    public void testSimpleProperties() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(service.getMessage());
    }
    
}
```

where `test-app-context.xml` is

```
<bean class="com.foo.bar.ExampleService">
    <property name="arg" value="${arg1}" />
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder />
```

and `ExampleService` is:

```
@Component
public class ExampleService implements Service {
    
    private String arg;
    
    public String getArg() {
        return arg;
    }

    public void setArg(String arg) {
        this.arg = arg;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return arg; 
    }
}
```

and the argument passed to the test is a `VM argument` (specified like `-Darg1=value1`) and **not** a `Program argument`.

Both in Eclipse accessed with *Right-Click* on the test class -> `Run As` -> `Run Configurations` -> `JUnit` -> `Arguments` tab -> `VM Arguments`.

Comment: The problem with that I think is that the while it allows the test  program to get the variables passeed in using -D, they will not be loaded into the Spring context.

Comment: Does not work. The first thing the Spring test will do is load the app-context.xml. Spring will then throw an IllegalStateException as one of the ${} placeholder variables will not have been defined. Declaring the variables themselves in the test itself using @Value therefore does not help.

Comment: That's strange. Works for me. I've updated my answer with another code sample.

Comment: Thanks Andrei. Problem was thst I was passing in args using 'program arguments', and not VM arguments